# build a simple remote dispatcher using multiprocessing.Managers

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Consider the following code :

Server :

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, BaseProxy, Process

def baz(aa) :
    l = []
    for i in range(3) :
      l.append(aa)
    return l

class SolverManager(BaseManager): pass

class MyProxy(BaseProxy): pass

manager = SolverManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey='mpm')
manager.register('solver', callable=baz, proxytype=MyProxy)

def serve_forever(server):
    try :
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

def runpool(n):
    server = manager.get_server()
    workers = []

    for i in range(int(n)):
        Process(target=serve_forever, args=(server,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runpool(sys.argv[1])
```

Client :

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, BaseProxy

import multiprocessing, logging

class SolverManager(BaseManager): pass

class MyProxy(BaseProxy): pass

def main(args) :
    SolverManager.register('solver')
    m = SolverManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey='mpm')
    m.connect()

    print m.solver(args[1])._getvalue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

If I run the server using only one process as `python server.py 1`

then the client works as expected. But if I spawn two processes (`python server.py 2`) listening for connections, I get a nasty error :

```
$python client.py ping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 24, in <module>
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "client.py", line 21, in main
    print m.solver(args[1])._getvalue()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 637, in temp
    authkey=self._authkey, exposed=exp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 894, in AutoProxy
    incref=incref)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 700, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 750, in _incref
    dispatch(conn, None, 'incref', (self._id,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 79, in dispatch
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 181, in handle_request
    result = func(c, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 402, in incref
    self.id_to_refcount[ident] += 1
KeyError: '7fb51084c518'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My idea is pretty simple. I want to create a server that will spawn a number of workers that will share the same socket and handle requests independently. Maybe I'm using the wrong tool here ?

The goal is to build a 3-tier structure where all requests are handled via an http server and then dispatched to nodes sitting in a cluster and from nodes to workers via the multiprocessing managers...

There is one public server, one node per machine and x number of workers on each machine depending on the number of cores... I know I can use a more sophisticated library, but for such a simple task (I'm just prototyping here) I would just use the multiprocessing library... Is this possible or I should explore directly other solutions ? I feel I'm very close to have something working here ... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to invent a wheel, many have invented before.

It sounds to me that you're looking for task queue where your server dispatches tasks to, and your workers execute this tasks.

I would recommend you to have a look at [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).